# HTML Anchor Link - Offseting Position

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

**I have Created an Example Page Below:**
http://glustik.com/glustik2/index.html

When you **Click the First Two Links** you can see how the Anchors Position to the top and not down (250 or so Pixels).

Is there a way to summon the anchors to a certain location on the window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery animate function to set the scrollTop to the wanted position.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#your-div").offset().top - YourHeadersHeight }, 500);
```

Comment: Actually, I just added Anchor Divs with Negative Margins. (the example is live) Does this make less sense? Or Good to Go?

Comment: I would go for the calculated scrollTop. But negative margins apparently do the trick too.